# XPath query to get node after some other node

Tags: xml, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am using "HtmlAgilityPack" to parse HTML content.
My target is to get number value.

```
<div>
    some content 1
    <br>
    some <b>content</b> 2
    <br>
    <b>NUMBER:</b>
    9788492688647
    <br>
    some content 3
    <br>
    some content 4
    </div>


aim:
 - get "9788492688647"

Anybody can tell me how to get value between  /div/b[2] and <br> ?
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
/div/b[2]/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

However, depending on how consistent the structure is, you might want to do something like:

```
/div/b[. = 'NUMBER:']/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

Comment: The first one works perfectly :), the second one throw exception incorrect syntax.
Great thanks :), that is what i was looking for.